# C++ How to loop through set in map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, containers

I am stuck on one problem in my school project: I need a set of numbers mapped to key number. `ZZ` is a class for big integers from the NTL library, but that's not important. My program always fails on the inner loop with the message that `it_set2` can't be iterable.

```
std::map<ZZ, std::set<ZZ>> mapa;  
std::map<ZZ, std::set<ZZ>>::iterator it_map;  
std::set<ZZ>::iterator it_set1, it_set2;    

for (it_map = mapa.begin(); it_map != mapa.end(); ++it_map) {       
    for (it_set1 = it_map->second.begin(); it_set1 != it_map->second.end(); ++it_set1) {
        for (it_set2 = ++it_set1; it_set2 != it_map->second.end(); ++it_set2) {
            /*
            some function that uses *it_set1, *it_set2
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your example is compiling and running for me. (https://ideone.com/mi2bFV)

Comment: @tgmath: Only for empty maps. I'd guess OP's map is not empty ;)

Comment: Then a failing example might help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem is in the most inner loop. If you want `it_set2` to point to the next element which `it_set1` is currently pointing to (but not actually incrementing `it_set1`) then you should change your third loop to the following: `for(it_set2 = it_set1; ++it_set2 != it_map->second.end(); )`.

This will make sure that you're not going out of bounds and not incrementing `it_set1` when not necessary.

Comment: A have also added this `if(*it_set1 == *it_set2){continue;}` so it`s ok now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you provide, I suspect you run into problems when hitting the last set-element in the second loop. Once you iterate over the last one, the third loop increments `it_set1` which then is the `end` iterator (as you were looking at the last element). The third for-loop terminates and the second loop executes its past-body instruction, which is `++it_set1` moving the iterator past the `end`, thereby invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: I improved my code by adding
    if(++it_set1 == it_map->second.end()){
        break;
    }
before lastloop but it didn`t help. Do you have solution?
Thank for reaction.

Comment: @MatejProcházka: Provide a complete example that people can reproduce. Otherwise, nobody will be able to help you.